# The view Expéditions.views.changelisteexpédition didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: python, django

I'm new in django developpemnt , in my view i have some elif conditions that mastring some functions, in execution on the last condition  i have this issue : 
The view Expéditions.views.changelisteexpédition didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

```
    def changelisteexpédition(request,id=id):
        if "Editer" in request.POST:
.......     
        elif "Bloquer" in request.POST :
....... 
        elif "Supprimer" in request.POST:
....... 
        elif "Annuler" in request.POST:
.......     
        elif "Débloquer" in request.POST :
....... 
        elif "Top Départ" in request.POST :
            trsp = transporteur.objects.all().order_by('id')
            obj = get_object_or_404(Expédition,id=request.POST.get("choix"))    
            form = TopdépartForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                Topdépart.objects.create(
                    Expédition = obj,
                    transporteur = request.POST.get("transporteur"),
                    chauffeur = request.POST.get("chauffeur"),
                    bl = request.POST.get("bl"),
                    plomb = request.POST.get("plomb"),
                    commentaire = request.POST.get("commentaire"),
                    date = request.POST.get("date"),
                    immatriculation = request.POST.get("immatriculation")   
                    )           
                obj.statut = "Expédié"
                obj.transporteur = request.POST.get("transporteur")
                obj.chauffeur =  request.POST.get("chauffeur")
                obj.immatriculation = request.POST.get("immatriculation")
                obj.save()
                a = Commande.objects.get(numcommande=obj.numcommande)
                a.quantitélivrée = obj.quantitélivrée
                a.statut = "Expédié"
                a.save()
                j = Ligneexpédition.objects.filter(numcommande=obj.numcommande)
                for i in j :
                    c = Articles.objects.get(sku=i.sku)
                    c.stockexpedié = c.stockexpedié + i.quantitélivrée
                    c.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect("asnintransit")
            else :
                form = TopdépartForm()                      
            context = {
                'form':form,`enter code here`
                'obj':obj,
                'trsp':trsp
            }
            return render(request,'topdépart.html',context)
```

I need some help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In this part:

```
else:
    form = TopdépartForm()
```

You are not returning a render() method, so basically I'm telling you to indent the last portion of your code like this:

```
else :
    form = TopdépartForm()                      
    context = {
        'form':form,`enter code here`
        'obj':obj,
        'trsp':trsp
    }
    return render(request,'topdépart.html',context)
```

I'm 90% confident it will make your code work, if not, reach again I'll try to replicate